# Blank Page when creating a route manager

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting a new project in order to learn repo. At first, it's a very basic structure.

This is the code which will handle routing in my app

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Main from './pages/main'
import Repo from './repos'

export default function RouteManager(){
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" component ={Main}/>
                <Route exact path="/repo" component ={Repo}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

In theory, it should redirect to two disntict pages

Main page

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Main(){
    return(
        <h1>Main</h1>
    )
}
```

And there's also a repo page

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Repos(){
    return(
        <h1>Repos</h1>
    )
}
```

And here's the App file

```
import React from 'react'
import RouteManager from './routes'
function App() {
  return (
    
    <RouteManager/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

However, when testing the redirect tool, it shows me only a blank page. What could be wrong

The index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This all looks correct to me. And just to verify: you are using react-router v6, not v5, right?

Comment: For completeness, could you also add your `index.html` file?

Comment: Yep. I am using react-router v6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v6 of react-router the `Route` components no longer have a `component` parameter. It is now called `element` and takes jsx, see https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route.

Try:

```
export default function RouteManager(){
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Main />}/>
                <Route exact path="/repo" element={<Repo />}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear. Please don't forget to accept the answer and/or upvote.